# How can I calculate the sum of the int field for each Element using Stream API?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the next classes:

```
public class Order {
    private List<Element> elements;
}

public class Element {
    private int size;
}
```

And I need to create the method which returns the map with orders as `keys` and the sum of every element's size in the order as `values` using Stream API.

For example for

```
List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

orders.add(Order.createOrder(List.of(element1, element2, element3)));
orders.add(Order.createOrder(List.of(element3)));
```

we should get:

```
{order1 = 75, order2 = 30}
```

because `size` of `element1 = 20, element2 = 25, element3 = 30`

I tried something like this:

```
private static Map<Order, Integer> calculate(List<Order> orders) {
    return  orders.stream()
        .flatMap(o -> o.getElements().stream())
        .mapToInt(el -> el.getSize())
        .sum();
}
```

but this code counts the sum of all element's sizes. What can I do here? Will be thankful for any advice!

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès you mean I need to create record again?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I know how to count the sum of element's size, but in the end how to map this sums by the orders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is: foreach order, sum the elements:

```
class Element {
    private int value;
    public Element(int v) { value = v; }
    public int getValue() { return value; }
    public String toString() { return ""+value; }
}
class Order {
    public String name;
    public List<Element> elements;
    public Order(String n, List<Element> l) { name = n; elements = l; }
    public String toString() { return name; }
    public static Order createOrder(String n, List<Element> l) { return new Order(n,l); }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String []a) {
        List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

        Element element1 = new Element(20);
        Element element2 = new Element(25);
        Element element3 = new Element(30);

        orders.add(Order.createOrder("order1", List.of(element1, element2, element3)));
        orders.add(Order.createOrder("order2", List.of(element3)));

        Map<Order,Integer> r = orders.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> o, o -> o.elements.stream().mapToInt(Element::getValue).sum()));
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

which gives:

```
{order1=75, order2=30}
```

if you want a `Map<String,Integer>` then:

```
Map<String,Integer> r = orders.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Object::toString, o -> o.elements.stream().mapToInt(Element::getValue).sum()));
```